# C# setting tab causes freeze

Tags: c#

Whenever I set the selected tab

```
tcTabs.SelectedTab = secondTab;
```

The entire application freezes without any error messages.
How can I fix this?

Some code

```
    private void downloadThread()
    {
        WebClient wc;


        wc = new WebClient();

        lbStatus.Text = "Creating directory";
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Program Files\\foo");

        pbMain.Value = 33;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        lbStatus.Text = "Downloading files";
        wc.DownloadFile("http://website.net/foo.exe", "C:\\Program Files\\foo\\foo.exe");

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        pbMain.Value = 66;

        lbStatus.Text = "Creating shortcuts";
        appShortcutToDesktop("C:\\Program Files\\foo\\foo.exe", "foo");

        pbMain.Value = 100;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        tcMain.Width = 186;
        tcMain.Height = 122;
        this.Width = 186;
        this.Height = 122;

        tcMain.SelectedTab = tpName;

        while (tcMain.SelectedTab != tpAddWebsites)
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

        tcMain.Width = 218;
        tcMain.Height = 147;
        this.Width = 218;
        this.Height =  147;
    }
```

Picture of the application after the selectedtab is set to tpName
http://segnosis.net/screenshots/b1ktn5.png

Comment: it seems that you have `bad` code in the secondTab constructor (or smth that is called on initialization). there is nothing to say on this. try analysing only the secondTab code step-by-step (without tabcontrol and other stuff); probably you have an infinite loop in there

Comment: The second tab works fine for about 1 second. Im switching the tabs in a thread.

Comment: Make sure the thread you are operating on is the UI thread.

Comment: What this other commenters are saying is that we need more info, you've given everybody next to nothing to go on. Post some code.

Comment: I would like to echo @ROBOlav's comment, based on you saying you are switching tabs in a thread you MUST perform the code you list above in the UI thread. If you are on the other thread then you need to use an `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` call to run the code in the UI thread.

Comment: Looking at the code you posted now, you are adjusting the dimensions of the tab control and setting text on the form, all of that work has to be done on the UI thread using an Invoke, basically doing the same thing that Jim answered, but don't just do it for the tabs, do it for the dimension changes as well as the label settings.

Answer (score 7):

If you're switching tabs in a thread, you need to use [Form.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.invoke.aspx):

```
void SetSecondTab()
{
    tcTabs.SelectedTab = secondTab;
}

void SwitchTabsFromThread()
{
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => { SetSecondTab(); }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be insistent on seeing an answer that uses a `delegate` then you could (if your downloadThread code is in your `Form`) just do something like this at each location that you are touching the UI:

```
BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)( () => lbStatus.Text = "Creating directory"; ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you are accessing UI elements from what I assume (based on the method name alone) is a non-UI thread. You simply cannot do this. You cannot do anything with any UI form or control from a thread other than the main UI thread; the only exception being the `ISynchronizeInvoke` methods. You are going to have to reconsider how the application is architected and make some significant changes. The freezing issue is just one, albiet visible, symptom of a broader problem.